# what's the difference between this two video url using exoplayer in android?

Tags: android, exoplayer

here is two urls. First is "https://28api.haii.io/media/video/video_60_1.mp4",and Second is "https://28api.haii.io/media/video/video_70_1.mp4". When I load first video url, it load and play well. But when I load second url, the second video is broken. I can here only audio. So I tried comparing this two video by download.. but I can't understand the difference between this two url. Both are mp4 encoded video. But Exoplayer only load well at first but not at second.... how can I solve this... help me...

```
private fun initializePlayer() {
        if (player == null) {
            val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector()
            trackSelector.setParameters(
                trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSizeSd()
            )
            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context,trackSelector)
            binding.videoPlayer.player = player
            binding.videoPlayer.useController=false
            binding.playerControl.player = binding.videoPlayer.player
            mediaSource = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaList[currentIndex].url))
            player!!.prepare(mediaSource,false,false)
            player!!.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
            player!!.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
            setAudioFocus()
            player!!.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
                override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                    when (playbackState) {
                        Player.STATE_IDLE -> {
                        }
                        Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> {
                        }
                        Player.STATE_READY -> {

                        }
                        Player.STATE_ENDED -> {
                            showPlayButton()
                            player!!.seekTo(currentWindow, 0)
                            showThumbnailImage()
                            player!!.playWhenReady = false
                        }

                        else -> {

                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }

    }

    private fun getVideoSource(url :String){
        videoUrl = url
        var mediaSource = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url))
        player!!.prepare(mediaSource)
        playbackPosition=0
        player!!.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
        player!!.playWhenReady = false
    }
```

Comment: I personally can't play second video at all through any browser, it works through a media player so perhaps video file itself is corrupted and needs to be reencoded.

Comment: if you click the url, u can see the video at browser, but not exoplayer... so that's why I ask for this question.

Comment: `mp4` is simply the container, you should find out what codecs are used, if you can confirm they are the same, and supported, then the file is probably corrupted.